# bootstrap navigation bar on collapse swinging effect

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, navigation, hamburger-menu

I have a problem with my navigation bar when it collapses because my list have a weird swinging effect when it is displayed when I click on my hamburger button.

Here it is the css code:

```
.navbar-header{float:none}
a.navbar-brand{float:none}
img.brand{display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;text-align:center;width:47%}
.collapse.navbar-collapse{float: none;text-align: center;padding-left:4%;padding-right: 4%}
.collapse.navbar-collapse ul{float: none;display: inline-block}
```

and if someone wants to have a look, here's the link:

http://chickapea.larchedigitalmedia.com/

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all your custom styles on the native bootstrap classes. This is going to cause stuff to break. I think your "swinging" is from the fact your `text-align: center;` class is on your `.collapse` class. The `.collapse` class goes away when you click the hamburger button so all the properties on your `.collapse` class go away, too.

Create custom classes on the elements and apply the CSS to the custom classes versus the bootstrap classes.